# Theorem of Primes in Arithmetic Progression

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I'm am studying number theory and I came across this theorem by Dirichlet but the proof is not given and I do not know how to prove it

Can anyone help me?

$Theorem$ $of$ $Primes$ $in$ $Arithmetic$ $Progression:$
If $a$ and $b$ are integers, with $(a,b)=1$ so the arithmetic progression $an+b$, $n=1,2,3,...$ has infinite primes.

Comment: many books have correct proofs. Not easy, and not something that would fit well in an answer box on this site.

Comment: This is not an easy result!  In certain cases, such as $4n+3$, there are ways to get at it but the general theorem requires a lot of machinery.

Comment: A classical reference is [this book](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4757-5579-4_8) by Tom Apostol. There are very many references at MSE, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11330/dirichlets-theorem-on-primes-in-arithmetic-progression?rq=1), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373370/dirichlets-theorem-on-arithmetic-progressions) etc. Just look at the links on the right margin.

Comment: This is mentioned at one of Dietrich's links in a comment, several special cases that do not require any analytic approach: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/dirichleteuclid.pdf

Comment: In general, the idea is that $F(s) =\displaystyle \sum_{p^k \text{ prime power }, p^k \equiv b \bmod a} p^{-sk}$ has the nice property that $F(s) =\frac{1}{\phi(a)} \sum_{\chi \bmod a} \overline{\chi(b)} \log L(s,\chi)$ where $L(s,\chi) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \chi(n) n^{-s}$ are the Dirichlet L-functions. And hence to prove Dirichlet's theorem it is enough to prove $F(s)$ is not analytic at $s=1$.

Comment: Definitely agree with @WillJagy and @lulu; however, the traditional analytic approach is definitely not the only way to arrive at the elementary conclusion that in general there are infinitely many primes in any arithmetic progression if the residue and the modulus are coprime.